How to make it so that when uninstalling an app, the uninstaller always runs as admin?
I recently realised that I had a lot of useless apps on my computer, so I try to uninstall them. However, it always fails (through my research is due to the file not running as admin) but I am already an administrator.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You should be able to simply right click the uninstaller and select "run as Administrator".  Have you tried that?

BTW, there are third-party tools such as Bulk Crap Uninstaller, https://www.bcuninstaller.com, and many alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-crap-uninstaller/, to make the task easier and more through. If you're removing multiple apps, try one... but check any download at VirusTotal.com before using.

i cant find the uninstaller file, i try to uninstall from the windows programs menu. BTW its an msi file
